# Can you say "New York is in night time"?

Tags: complements, existentials, time-words

> 1. New York **is in** night time.
> 2. New York **is** night time.

Which one is correct?

I know that you use "It's night time in New York", but does the inversion sound wrong apart from the grammar problem?

Comment: What are you trying to say with these phrases? Or are you just trying to get the inversion? The inversion would be "In New York it's nighttime."

Answer (score 2):

No. 2 is definitely wrong; it's essentially saying that New York is night-time; night-time is New York. New York obviously cannot be night-time.

As for No. 1, I have never heard anyone use it. It makes sense, but I wouldn't consider it to be strictly grammatical. As you mention in your question, it's best to use *It's night-time in New York*.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem with the inversion is that night-time is enveloping /surrounding New York and not the other way around.  Therefore, it is ok to say it is night-time in New York, but New York is not in(side) of Night-time.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thanks. Your reasoning seems interesting. What's wrong with night time surrounding New York? It seems to me that makes more sense than New York surrounding night time.?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic versions would use a "dummy" subject:

***It* is night-time in New York**

or simply

***It's* night in New York**.

Another melodramatic possibility:

New York is still in darkness when Londoners begin their day.

Answer (score 0):

"New York is in night time" is an out-of-this world expression.  Literally.

Astronauts on the space station making similar statements.  They watch the earth from a different perspective, and at some places in their orbit, are able to see the portion of the planet that is in daylight and the portion experiencing night.

It would be unusual, though, for a person on the ground to think of it from that perspective.